Excel : I want to count value in cells until a specific column number is reached. Any way to do it?
Below is my data in excel -



Name
01.04
02.04
03.04
04.04
05.04
06.04
07.04
08.04
09.04
10.04




ABC
H
A

O
O
A
A
A




DEF
H


O
O

A
A




GHI
H


O
O
A

A




XYZ
H


O
O








I want to get inputs from user in excel and count number of "A" up to that date as mentioned in the top row.
Eg.

if user input is Name - GHI and date - 06.04 , then output should be 1.
if user input is Name - ABC and date - 06.04 , then output should be 2.

Any suggestions on how can I do it?
I have tried COUNTIF but not able to pass variable column number to it.
Also, I do not want to use VBA as using them gives other troubles in Excel.

Can't you use CountIFS() in case of multiple criteria?

=COUNTIF(INDEX(B2:K5, MATCH(M1, A2:A5, 0), 1):INDEX(B2:K5, MATCH(M1, A2:A5, 0), MATCH(M2, B1:K1, 0)), "A")

or
=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A5=M1)*(B1:K1<=M2)*(B2:K5="A"))

or if you really hate anyone who will ever have to debug this spreadsheet and you have Excel 365:
=LET(
    userInput, M1,
    dateInput, M2,
    userRange, A2:A5,
    dateRange, B1:K1,
    dataStart, B2:K5,
    userRow, XMATCH(userInput, userRange, 0),
    dateCol, XMATCH(dateInput, dateRange, 1),
    dataRange, INDEX(dataStart, userRow, 1):INDEX(dataStart, userRow, dateCol),
    isA, IF(dataRange="A", 1, 0),
    totalA, SUM(isA),
    totalA
)



=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A5=M1)*(B1:K1<=M2)*(B2:K5="A")) is the only reasonable and sufficient solution here.

@rotabor - reasonable is boring.

Use SUMPRODUCT().
=SUMPRODUCT((B2:K5="A")*(B1:K1<=D10)*(A2:A5=D9))

Using FILTER().
=SUM(--(FILTER(FILTER(B2:K5,B1:K1<=D10),A2:A5=D9)="A"))



Just to demonstrate that you can use Countifs (as suggested by @Dominique) in a simple fashion using the fact that index(,,0) gives you the whole row:
=COUNTIFS(B$1:K$1,"<="&N2,INDEX(B$2:K$5,MATCH(M2,A$2:A$5,0),0),"A")


